# ADODB - Excel - VBA: AddNew Typeconflict Lookup Column

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a problem. I have a Sharepoint 2013 teamsite and a Excel 2010 installation. I'm using the Microsoft Active X Data Objects 2.8 Library; Data Objects 6.1 and Data Objects Recordset 6.0/2.8 are also available but not used/tryed yet.

At my sharepoint list i have one lookup column to make a connections between the two lists.

No I'm using following code to put some entrys with a click on a button on my sharepoint list.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddNewEntry()

Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

Dim mySQL As String

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [interactive_turtle];"

With cnt
    .ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=0;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=xxxxxxxxxxxxx;LIST={xxxxxxxxxxxx};"
    .Open
End With

rst.Open mySQL, cnt, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

rst.AddNew
    rst.Fields("process") = [E6]
    rst.Fields("output") = [H6]
    rst.Fields("Input") = [B6]
    rst.Fields("rules") = [H10]
    rst.Fields("personal") = [H2]
    rst.Fields("material") = [B2]
    rst.Fields("xxxxxxxxx") = [B10]
    rst.Fields("audit") = [E10]
rst.Update

If CBool(rst.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) = True Then cnt.Close
Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

the lookup column is: rst.Fields("audit") = [E10].

If I run this code there is a type conflict for the lookup column. How can i fix this and put some entry in the lookup column?

~~~~~~
If you know something with another connector or another method to put data from excel to sharepoint let me know. I'm not fixed using ADODB!
~~~~~~

Thanks in advance.

Best wishes

Comment: How do you mean type conflict?  Also you can just use `if rst.state<>adstateclosed then rst.close`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav If i write on my excel-file something in the field audit (text) and want to upload it to sharepoint there is a error: runtime error -2147352571 (80020005). type conflict. any other field (single line of text on sharepoint) is working only the one specific field (lookup column on sharepoint) isn't

Comment: try debug window rst.Fields("audit").type then look at the ado types, it may be something that you need to format, guessing a date/time? http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_datatypes.asp

Comment: if i get the raw data from the sharepoint list i got for the lookup column for example: 13 | Item instead of the text that is stored in the list. on Sharepoint i see: N. America on my excel file i see 13 | Item (in two different cells after one synchronisation)// and in my excel file i write text. i think this is the mismatch.

Comment: mySQL = "SELECT * FROM [interactive_turtle];"  once this has been opened to a recordset, use the .type from the field to get its type, based on what you are saying it looks like N.America is the item with an index in another table of 13?

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string "RetrieveIds=Yes", this makes the data on the LOOKUP column to be IDs rather than Texts.

While updating back, you need to give ID of the looked up column rather than plain text. For the Lookup Column ID, you need to go to SourceList of the SharePoint and find the corresponding ID.